# Proving $\max\{|P(x)|,1\leq x\leq2\}\leq C_N·\max\{|P(x)|,0\leq x \leq 1\}, P\in E_N$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Let $E_N$ be the space of polynomials $P(x)$ of order $\leq N$. Prove there exist a constant $C_N>0$ so that $$\max\{|P(x)|,1\leq x\leq2\}\leq C_N·\max\{|P(x)|,0\leq x \leq 1\}, P\in E_N$$

What I've done: $P_1=\max\{|P(x)|,1\leq x\leq2\}=a_n2^n+a_{n-1}2^{n-1}+...+a_0$ where $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Then, $P_1\leq 2^n ·(a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+...+a_0)=P_2=C_N·\max\{|P(x)|,0\leq x \leq 1\}$

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct answer? This is a question for students who just started a course in multivariable calculus. My answer does not use anything we have worked in class, that is why I am unsure of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's far from enough. Your assumption that $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ is a very limiting one. From it follows that the $P(x)$ is increasing on non-negative $x$, such that the maximum on the left side is $P(2)$ and on the right side $P(1)$. Then you made the right choice of $C_N=2^N$. Generally though, with negative coefficients, all bets are off at which point $|P(x)|$ takes its maximum on $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$.

Comment: @BenW We are taking the absolute value, so $max_{x\in[0,1]}|P(x)|=-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly true that 
$$
\max_{1\le x\le2}|P(x)|\le2^N\sum_{k=0}^N|a_k|.
$$
What is not so clear is an inequality in the other direction, that is
$$
\max_{0\le x\le 1}|P(x)|\ge C_N\sum_{k=0}^N|a_k|.
$$
If the coefficients are nonnegative, then it holds with $C_N=1$, but the general case needs some more work.

Since you are studying multivariable calculus, you have probably learned about norms, and that all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional vector spaces. Prove that for any interval $[a,b]$
$$
\|P\|_{a,b}=\max_{a\le x\le b}|P(x)|
$$
is a norm on the $N+1$ dimensional vector space $E_N$ and you are done.

Comment: How is $E_N$ a $N+1$ vector space? The elements of $E_N$ are polynomials, not vectors, right? Another question, if $||P||_{0,1}$ is equivalent to the norm $||P||_{1,2}$ then there also exists a $B_N$ so that $\max\{|P(x)|,1\leq x\leq2\}\geq B_N·\max\{|P(x)|,0\leq x \leq 1\}, P\in E_N$, right?

Comment: What is a vector? An element of a vector space. And $E_N$ is a vector space with the operations of addition of polynomials and multiplication of a polynomial by a scalar. You can identify $P$ with the "vector" formed by its coefficients. And to the second question, yes.

Comment: Do you know any method that can extract an explicit value of $C_N$?